# cy.visit() failing with error from embedded page

Tags: cypress

The below code is giving error

```
cy.visit("https://test.backoffice.sitemanager.ability.abb")
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRIEv.png)

Where is this error coming from, how to fix it since I am not able to login until this message is  dismissed!

Comment: When does that error occur?

Comment: When i run this code

Comment: It looks like something thrown by your application. What does the cypress test fail message report?

Comment: Sorry for delay, no I do not print anything from application...not sure from where it is coming...no logs from cypress too...how to find the root of this?

Comment: It looks like it may be specific for your application. Can you reproduce it manually?

Comment: That is problem, when visiting the site from browser directly no pop-up only from cypress we see the pop-up. Can you please try the code, I have given cy.visit("https://test.backoffice.sitemanager.ability.abb") or cy.visit("https://sitemanager-wa-test-02.azurewebsites.net")